# Camel move file on failure

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to write a route to scan 'input' directory, if a .gz file is found, extract contents to secondary directory, and if an error occurs (e.g. corrupt .gz) then it moves the file to an error directory

What actually happens is that the file starts to write the contents out correctly, then an error occurs -a GZLIB exception, the original is correctly put in the error directory BUT the .gz in 'input' is not deleted because of the exception

So the route will continously open, start to extract then fail the file and keep repeating over and over forever. I need it to remove the file from 'input' directory when it fails so it won't be re-processed. I expected the .to( ) to a file location to achieve this as it usually behaves as a move.

```
onException( Exception.class )
     .to( "file://error_directory" )
.end()

from( "file://input" )
.choice()
    .when( {filename matches *.gz} )
        {unzip Gzip contents}
        .to( "file://output" )
    .when( ) ... 
.end()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `onException` you can use the `moveFailed` option directly on the file endpoint in the file consumer. Then if there was an exception the original file would be moved.

So something like

```
from( "file://input?moveFailed=error_directory" )
.choice()
    .when( {filename matches *.gz} )
        {unzip Gzip contents}
        .to( "file://output" )
    .when( ) ... 
.end()
```

You can read more about `moveFailed` in the Camel doc: http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: @Claus Ibsen If file move fails and endpoint uses 'moveFailed', will it log the filename in logs?